# asp.net page maker (form maker)

Tags: asp.net

please introduce some form maker(page maker) for asp.net.
like Iron speed.
that enable us to generate form or user control from database tables.
thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Asp.Net Dynamic Data](http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata)

There are tutorial videos at the link provided.

It's quick, simple, powerful, and easy to customize once you learn how it works.  (And provided you understand ASP.NET in general.

And it's free.

Comment: thank you:)
is it make controls From my table?
i am looking at it now.
does it  changed on vs2010?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest also this one

http://www.hkvstore.com/aspnetmaker/